# Where do I find the old Bing Client ID and Bing Client Secret

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

Hi since BING has changed to Azure cognitive and I need to provide the keys which I can find anymore at all. Who can help me out with this.

I need the old:

Bing Client ID
Bing Client Secret

//Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can still find your subscription key by signing in. 
https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/bing/search.

1. Got to My Account.
2. The primary account key and customer ID are listed on the page.

You can select ‘Account Keys’ on the left tab also to see additional keys you may have created.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the client ID/secret scheme for authorization is being end-of-life'd on Dec-15-2016.

You should get Azure API keys instead.  The [migration guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/mt707570.aspx) should help you move forward.